# Create new dataframe column from a shifted existing column

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe with open, high, low, close prices of a stock. I want to add an additional column that has the percent change between today's open and yesterday's high. This is my current implementation, however, the resulting column contains percent changes between the current day's high and open.

df

```
  open  high  low  close
0 100   110   95   103
1 103   113   103   111
2 111   132   109   124
3 124   136   114   130
```

My attempt (incorrect):

```
df['prevhigh_curropen'] = (df['open'] - df['high']).shift(-1) / df['high'].shift(-1)
```

Output (incorrect):

```
  open  high  low  close  prevhigh_curropen
0 100   110   95   103    -0.091
1 103   113   103  111    -0.089
2 111   132   109  124    -0.159
3 124   136   114  130    -0.088
```

Desired output:

```
  open  high  low  close  prevhigh_curropen
0 100   110   95   103    nan
1 103   113   103  111    -0.064
2 111   132   109  124    -0.018
3 124   136   114  130    -0.061
```

Is there a non-iterative way to do this like I attempted above?

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df[['open', 'high']].head(10).to_string(index=False))` please?

Comment: It seems like you're just shifting the wrong direction `(df['open'] - df['high'].shift()) / df['high'].shift()`

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is wrong, you have to use `df['high'].shift()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'open': range(1, 11), 'high': range(1, 11)})
df['prevhigh_curropen'] = df['open'].sub(df['high'].shift()) \
                                    .div(df['high'].shift()) \
                                    .mul(100)
```

```
>>> df
   open  high  prevhigh_curropen
0     1     1                NaN
1     2     2         100.000000
2     3     3          50.000000
3     4     4          33.333333
4     5     5          25.000000
5     6     6          20.000000
6     7     7          16.666667
7     8     8          14.285714
8     9     9          12.500000
9    10    10          11.111111
```

For your sample the output is:

```
>>> df
   open  high  low  close  prevhigh_curropen
0   100   110   95    103                NaN
1   103   113  103    111          -6.363636
2   111   132  109    124          -1.769912
3   124   136  114    130          -6.060606
```

The first value is `NaN` because we don't know the `high` value from the previous day.

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify the terms slightly from `(a - b) / b` to `(a / b) - (b / b)` to `(a / b) - 1`.

Mathematical Operators:

```
df['prevhigh_curropen'] = (df['open'] / df['high'].shift()) - 1
```

or with Series Methods:

```
df['prevhigh_curropen'] = df['open'].div(df['high'].shift()).sub(1)
```

*The benefit here is that we only need to shift once, and maintain 1 copy of `df['high'].shift()`

Resulting `df`:

```
   open  high  low  close  prevhigh_curropen
0   100   110   95    103                NaN
1   103   113  103    111          -0.063636
2   111   132  109    124          -0.017699
3   124   136  114    130          -0.060606
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'open': [100, 103, 111, 124],
    'high': [110, 113, 132, 136],
    'low': [95, 103, 109, 114],
    'close': [103, 111, 124, 130]
})
```